# Find the disk-space usage of a directory and all it's files

Tags: ls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know the size of a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/how-to-know-the-size-of-a-directory)

If I run

```
ls -lh
```

then any given directory is just shown as 4.0K. How can I can make it consider the files the directory refers to as well?

Comment: marking a question as a duplicate without linking to the duplicate is like having sex without an orgasm...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `du -h` and all directories and their subdirectories are being aggregated. (The -h makes it human readable as in useful units like MB, GB or KB)

Comment: -h does not show the total size of the directories including it's contents

Comment: Really helpful to add --max-depth=1 to only show disk space on the first level of forlders