# How do I get the size of a directory on the command line?

Tags: command-line, ls, disk-usage

I tried to obtain the size of a directory (containing directories and sub directories) by using the `ls` command with option `l`. It seems to work for files (`ls -l file name`), but if I try to get the size of a directory (for instance, `ls -l /home`), I get only 4096 bytes, although altogether it is much bigger.

Comment: 1) Strictly speaking, you can't.  Linux has directories, not folders. 2) There's a difference between the size of a directory (which is a special file holding inodes that point to other files), and the size of the contents of that directory.  As others have pointed out, the du command provides the latter, which is what it appears you want.

Comment: as you seem to be new, I'll just point out the helpful `-h` option you can add to the `-l` option (i.e. `ls -lh`) to get the sizes of files to be printed out in human-friendly notation like 1.1M instead of 1130301.


The "h" in the `du -hs` command that @sam gave as the answer for your question about directories also means "human-readable", and it also appears in `df -h` which shows the human readable amounts of used and free space on disk.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[How do I determine the total size of a directory (folder) from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224)*

Comment: `du -sh -- *` works for me.

Comment: Very similar: [Tracking down where disk space has gone on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125429)

Answer (score 2200, accepted):

`du -sh file_path`

**Explanation**

- `du` (**d**isc **u**sage) command estimates file_path space usage
- The options `-sh` are (from `man du`):

  ```
    -s, --summarize
           display only a total for each argument

    -h, --human-readable
           print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
  ```

  To check more than one directory and see the total, use `du -sch`:

  ```
    -c, --total
           produce a grand total
  ```

Comment: ...unless you have hardlinks ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951883/du-counting-hardlinks-towards-filesize

Comment: It works very nice with `find`  
e.g. to count the amount of space in specific subdirectories  in current path:  
`$ find . -type d -name "node_modules" -prune -exec du -sh {} \;`

Comment: @Rmano is there a single command that works with hardlinks?

Comment: @CharlieParker no that I know of...

Comment: I'm looking right now at a folder I just copied from an external drive. It contains four files (no hardlinks). `du -ba $folder` reports that each of these files is identical in size across the copied folders, but the total at the folder level does not match. `du -bs`, `du -h`, etc., same answer. (One folder size is six bytes more than the sum of the files; the other is ~10% larger.) I've seen this issue before comparing a folder on an external drive. Is there any unix command that will reliably report two folders containing identical files as being the same "size"?

Comment: Option `--si` like `-h`, but use powers of 1000 not 1024.

Answer (score 495):

Just use the `du` command:

```
du -sh -- *
```

will give you the cumulative disk usage of all non-hidden directories, files etc in the current directory in human-readable format.

You can use the `df` command to know the free space in the filesystem containing the directory:

```
df -h .
```

Comment: `du -sh *` starts throwing "unknown option" errors if any of the files in that dir begin with a dash. Safer to do `du -sh -- *`

Comment: `du -sh *` doesn't show memory usages of hidden folders

Comment: `du -sh -- * .*` to include dotfiles. This is useful to include a possibly large `.git` directory, for example. Alternatively in zsh you can `setopt globdots` to glob dotfiles by default.

Comment: What does the `--` do? I know it applies to shell *built-ins* to end option arguments, but `du` is not a built-in, and I don't see this usage documented for `du`: https://linux.die.net/man/1/du

Comment: Sometimes you'll want to add `-b` (`--apparent-size`)

Comment: (--) is used in most bash built-in commands and many other commands to signify the end of command options, after which only positional parameters are accepted. 
 [`source`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)

Answer (score 320):

`du` is your friend. If you just want to know the total size of a directory then jump into it and run:

```
du -hs
```

If you also would like to know which sub-folders take up how much disk space?! You could extend this command to:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr
```

which will give you the size of all sub-folders (level 1). The output will be sorted (largest folder on top).

Comment: It seems on some (perhaps older?) versions of linux, sort does not have an h switch, and therefore the next best command I could find is: du -c --max-depth=1 | sort -rn

Comment: @richhallstoke if you use [`ncdu`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342796/139857) the files are sorted by descending size by default.

Comment: just wanted to note that on osx `du` appears to use `-d` instead of `--max-depth`

Comment: to avoid the line for current directory in the result, just add star (idea from Pacifist, above): `du -h --max-depth=1 * | sort -h`

Answer (score 137):

`du` can be complicated to use since you have to seemingly pass 100 arguments to get decent output.  And figuring out the size of hidden folders is even tougher.

**Make your life easy and use `ncdu`**.

[image: ncdu]

You get per folder summaries that are easily browsable.

Comment: checked out `ncdu` and would like to point out to others: when you're hunting for those files that are bloating some directory this utility is extremely useful as it displays size tapes/indicators which make the culprit(s) stand out. Overall this offers the right amount of interactivity which may be particularly useful in command-line only environments.

Answer (score 42):

Others have mentioned `du`, but I would also like to mention [Ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/scr) -- which is an ncurses version of `du` and provides interactivity: You can explore the directory hierarchy directly and see the sizes of subdirectories.

Answer (score 31):

The `du` command shows the disk usage of the file.

The `-h` option shows results in human-readable form (e.g., 4k, 5M, 3G).

```
du -h (file name)
```

Answer (score 29):

```
df -h .; du -sh -- * | sort -hr
```

This shows how much disk space you have left on the current drive and then tells you how much every file/directory takes up. e.g.,

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2       206G  167G   29G  86% /
115M    node_modules
2.1M    examples
68K     src
4.0K    webpack.config.js
4.0K    README.md
4.0K    package.json
```

Comment: FYI, it seems to report the size-on-disk. i.e., it'll probably be padded to the nearest 4KB.

Answer (score 29):

All of the above examples will tell you the size of the data *on disk* (i.e. the amount of disk space a particular file is using, which is usually larger than the actual file size). There are some situations where these will not give you an accurate report, if the data is not actually stored on this particular disk and only inode references exist.

In your example, you have used ls -l on a single file, which will have returned the file's actual size, NOT its size on disk.

If you want to know the actual file sizes, add the -b option to du.

```
du -csbh .
```

Comment: Yes.  I'm using sdfs which compresses & dedups the files, so I couldn't figure out why it was reporting such low numbers.  The actual size of the files with ls can be found by using: du -b

Answer (score 24):

personally I think this is best, if you don't want to use `ncdu`

```
# du -sh ./*
```

Comment: Thank you! A command to see the size of just the direct children -- avoiding the huge wall of text that displays when you use the regular "recursive" version.

Answer (score 17):

In order to get the total size of files under a directory, you can select the type by `find`

- For files only:

  ```
  find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c %s | awk '{total+=$1} END {printf("%.0f\n",total)}'
  ```
- For everything but directories (files + symlinks + sockets + fifos + devices + ...):

  ```
  find -not -type d -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c %s | awk '{total+=$1} END {printf("%.0f\n",total)}'
  ```

**Why not use `du`?**

The `du` command is easier but it will count all types of files, and you don't have an option to change it. For example, assuming the current directory has a file, an empty dir and a symlink:

```shellsession
$ ls -AlF
total 8,192
-rw-r--r-- 1 nordic nordic    29 Mar 28 19:05 abc
drwxr-xr-x 2 nordic nordic 4,096 Mar 28 19:06 gogo/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nordic nordic     3 Mar 28 19:06 s_gogo -> abc
    
$ find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c %s | awk '{total+=$1} END {printf("%.0f\n",total)}'
29
    
$ du -sb
8224    .
```

Comment: I would use `-not -type d` to sum not only sizes of ordinary files (`-type f`) but also sizes of symbolic links and so on.

Comment: This is great, because you don't get the overhead required to store the files, but only the size of the files themselves.

Comment: This command could output things like `2.6957e+09`

Comment: try printf("%.0f\n",total)

Comment: @AdamTaylor Or show in MB: `| awk '{total+=$1} END {printf("%.0f MB\n",total/1024/1024)}'`

Answer (score 14):

Here is a function for your .bash_aliases

```
# du with mount exclude and sort
function dusort () {
    DIR=$(echo $1 | sed 's#\/$##')
    du -scxh $(mount | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq \
     | sed 's#/# --  exclude=/#') $DIR/* | sort -h
}
```

sample output:

```
$ dusort /
...
0       /mnt  
0       /sbin
0       /srv
4,0K    /tmp
728K    /home
23M     /etc
169M    /boot  
528M    /root
1,4G    /usr
3,3G    /var
4,3G    /opt
9,6G    total
```

for subdirs:

```
$ dusort .
$ dusort /var/log/
```

Answer (score 12):

I [use this command as root](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sudo+ls+-1d+*%2F+%7C+sudo+xargs+-I%7B%7D+du+%7B%7D+-sh+%26%26+csudo+du+-sh):

```
sudo ls -1d */ | sudo xargs -I{} du {} -sh && sudo du -sh
```

Answer (score 11):

One more variant:

```
du -h --max-dep=1
```

Answer (score 10):

Note that `du` prints the space that a directory occupy on the media which is usually bigger than just the total size of all files in the directory, because `du` takes into account the size of all auxiliary information that is stored on the media to organize the directory in compliance with file system format.

If the file system is compressible, then `du` may output even smaller number than the total size of all files, because files may be internally compressed by the file system and so they take less space on the media than just uncompressed information they contain. Same if there are sparse files.

if there are hard links in the directory, then `du` may print smaller value as well because several different files in the directory refer the same data on the media.

To get the straightforward total size of all files in the directory, the following one-line shell expression can be used (assuming a GNU system):

```
find . ! -type d -print0 | xargs -r0 stat -c %s | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

or even shorter:

```
find . ! -type d -printf '%s\n' | paste -sd+ - | bc
```

It just sums sizes of all non-directory files in the directory (and its subdirectories recursively) one by one. Note that for symlinks, it reports the size of the symlink (not of the file the symlink points to).

Comment: Very nice! This also works for blobfuse2 file system. To see MBs instead of bytes, instead of directly piping to bc, I'm now piping it to `awk '{print "(" $0 ")/1024/1024" }' | bc | awk '{ print $0 " MB" }'` :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use

`du -sh directory/`

and

`du -sh filename`

to know the space occupied by the folder or file.

`df -h`

will show the disk usage in human readable format -h does that.

There is also a gui based program called `Disk Usage Analyzer`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a POSIX script that will work with:

- A file
- Files
- A directory
- Directories

```sh
ls -A -R -g -o "$@" | awk '{n1 += $3} END {print n1}'
```